# paperclip - Invalid Parameter /Users PaperclipError: There was an error processing the thumbnail for stream

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, imagemagick, paperclip

Trying to run paperclip on windows on a mongrel server. Images won't upload, generates console log of

```
    Invalid Parameter - /Users
[paperclip] An error was received while processing: #<Paperclip::PaperclipError: There was an error processing the thumbnail for stream20110831-1316-1naludd>
```

The model code is

```
has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :large => "1280x800", :thumb => "128x80" }
```

Form code is

```
<%= simple_form_for @item,  :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_messages %>
    <%= f.input :name %>
    <%= f.input :price %>
    <%= f.input :description %>
    <%= f.input :image %>
    <%= f.association :section, :include_blank => false %>
 <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Imagemagick is installed, path is placed in the development.rb file. Tried multiple image formats (.jpg, .png, .gif) from multiple locations. Migration has been done. Any ideas?

EDIT: SOLVED. Turns out I made a super stupid mistake and put forward slashes in the path to imageMagick, forgot for a second windows uses backslashes.

Comment: Can you change the temp path in Paper clip or somewhere?  The problem you are having is the \ in the path I think, whichever way it is now reverse it if possible like to / or Windows thinks it is a switch.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the ImageMagick convert utility can't process your uploaded image temp file.

Can you dump the environment for your mongrel?  Especially wherever the Rails temp directory is.

I bet the fully qualified path to the 'tmp' directory in your Rails project isn't processable on windows when passed to ImageMagick, causing the thumbnail generation to fail.

Sadly, you may need to move your Rails project to a path that works.

Comment: Temp is in C:\Users\Marc Mailhot\My Documents\Aptana Studio 3 Workspace\Mahtay Menu\tmp. How would I dump my mongrel environment

Comment: You may need to alias that to a path without spaces I bet the spaces break the command line parsing.

Comment: So I should just copy the entire project into a folder w/ no spaces

Comment: Or use a windows symlink via junction: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896768

Comment: No, I have used Paperclip on Windows with Spaces in the path from Aptana, it works.  The cause is probably elsewhere.

Comment: It seems to be taking the /Users parts of the address as a parameter, not a path. This is before any spaces are in the path.

Answer (score 0):

Have the same problem, it aborts with the same error message when it tries to convert the image.

It's because `convert` is also a windows command (Better described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9035861/831465)).

Changing paperclip's `command_path` in `config/environments/development.rb` directly to imagemagick solves the problem:

```
Paperclip.options[:command_path] = 'C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.9.0-Q16'
```