# Image not resizing in the command prompt

Tags: resize, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I want to resize my image 200x200px but below command not working. I have successfully installed imagemagick in my computer.

```
convert current_image.png -resize 200 new_image.png
```

I have tried above command but not working. I am getting error message `Invalid Parameter - -resize`

Please let me know how to fix that?

[image]

Comment: Are you running under Windows? I suspect you are not using the `convert` program from ImageMagick but maybe the built-in Windows `CONVERT.EXE` which converts filesystems to NTFS. Try `convert -version` to see if you are using ImageMagick's convert program. Check your PATH.

Comment: Yes I am using windows.

Comment: Try `convert /?` and `convert -version` and say what they produce.

Comment: Updated question. Please check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are running the Windows built-in command called `CONVERT.EXE` which converts filesystems to NTFS and not the ImageMagick `convert` program.

You have two options... the first is best if you plan on using ImageMagick only one or two times, the second one is best if you plan on using ImageMagick often.

**Option 1**

Use the full path to ImageMagick's `convert` program every time you want to process images, e.g.:

```
C:\ImageMagick-6.9.2\convert image.png ...
```

Your installation path may differ from the one I guessed above.

**Option 2**

Edit your PATH so that the directory where you installed ImageMagick is near the start of the PATH so that Windows finds that one first. So, you need to click:

```
Start->Control Panel->System->Advanced->Environment Variables
```

Then edit the PATH so it looks like:

```
C:\ImageMagick-6.9-3;C:\other stuff
```

Specifically, the directory containing ImageMagick must come **before** `C:\Windows\System32` where the Windows file conversion tool lives.

After you do that, you will just be able to type `convert` and it will run ImageMagick `convert`.

Comment: No not shout my problem. Still coming same error. Please help me

Comment: Which directory have you installed ImageMagick in?

Comment: I have installed through command prompt `scoop install imagemagick` My imagemagick Path: `C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\scoop\apps\imagemagick\6.9.3-8;`

Comment: C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\row\Ruby22\bin;D:\xampp\mysql\bin;C:\Users\Use
r\AppData\Local\scoop\apps\imagemagick\6.9.3-8;C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\scoop
\shims;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\

Comment: You need to put ImageMagick **before** `C:\windows\system32` so put it at the very start of your PATH. Then start a new `Command Prompt` and try again.

Comment: Yes working perfect. Please update your answer Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

1. At first, check whether your path is set. (How? Mentioned above)
2. If you are using latest ImageMagick, try changing from `convert` to `magick`

There is another way to do this (I didn't try it)--

1. Replace `convert` with the path. For example `"C:\Program Files\ImageMagick\convert.exe"` (In the latest ImageMagick, replace `convert` with `magick`)
2. For reference: [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3060205/error-invalid-parameter-fom-imagemagick-convert-on-windows)

It works for me. Let me know if it works for you too. If you find any error in my answer, let me know also.